# Permissions issues with PyUSB on MacOSX when Running Script as Root?

Tags: python, macos, pyusb

I'm having some problems reading a digital scale using PyUSB in a Mac (On linux it works like a charm).

I don't know why do I have insufficient permissions even running the code as root user.

Here is the actual code: http://pastebin.com/nuzqGLp6 and this is the outcome: http://pastebin.com/F6DwGUXd

Running as root!

I don't know what the problem can be here, any help will be really appreciated.

Comment: Not really sure about this, but maybe another program is currently using the usb device, and the os won't let you use it?

Comment: Thanks, I'm not a mac user, and I can't find a way to see which processes might be using the device (I've been googling). Is there a way to identify and kill those processes?

Comment: I'm not sure, not a mac user myself. You could try asking in the [unix stack exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/), about finding processes that use a device.

Comment: I will be following both threads and see if a solutions comes out, for now I'll be using the node js wrapper. https://www.npmjs.org/package/dymo-scale